# Why status bar is cover by table view when adding pan gesture to View swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, navigation-drawer, statusbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a ViewController (LandingViewController) and one drawerViewController.
I am using SWRevealViewController and I added a gesture to Landing view but when it will open the DrawerViewController then it is covering status bar only once. I don't know why this is happening, But it is hiding once and after that working fine.

I am not using NavigationBar and I have a map view in my LandingViewController.
I have drawer button in my LandingViewController. 
If I will open or reveal the view by button it's working fine. But if I will open it by view it is hiding status bar.

Here below is my code :-

```
btnDrawerMenu.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside). 
//Reveal View Drawer menu
fileprivate func createReveal() {
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.width - 20
        self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0
        self.revealViewController().bounceBackOnOverdraw = false
        self.revealViewController().bounceBackOnLeftOverdraw = false

        self.revealViewController().toggleAnimationType = .easeOut
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: Yes I have fixed it.

Comment: Then maybe add your answer to your own question, there is a reason @OrenEdrich is asking.